# How to prepare data string but the string does not end with null

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, string, null

I want to make dataSet like `(11,22) , (11,22,33) , (11,22,33,44) , (11,null,33,44),(11,null,null,44),(11,null,33)`

but it should not end with null.
(means the dataSet string should not come `(11,22,null,null)` like this ).

```
hpVal=11, outputRpmVal=22,ratioVal=33,outputSpeedVal=44
```

Assume the above values will come to the arrayPrepareFunction. Anybody could you please help me to make the dataSet string like the above mentioned format?

while making the array set it should not use `else if`.

The dynamic data will come from user side. i will attach the screen shot. according to the user selection value will be change.

[image]

this is the select box order `hpVal`, `outputRpmVal`, `ratioVal`, `outputSpeedVal`.

For example: if user selects:
`(hpVal=11, outputRpmVal=null,ratioVal=33)`
the dataset should be like this `(11,null,33)`.

if user selects:
`(hpVal=11, outputRpmVal=null,ratioVal=null,outputSpeedVal=44)`
the dataset should be like this `(11,null,null,44)`.

if user selects: 
`(hpVal=11, outputRpmVal=22,ratioVal=null,outputSpeedVal=null)`
the dataset should be like this `(11,22)`.

```js
var dataSet,avoid=",null";

function arrayPrepareFunction(hpVal,outputRpmVal,ratioVal,outputSpeedVal){
  dataSet="("+hpVal+","+outputRpmVal+","+ratioVal+","+outputSpeedVal+")";

  dataSet = dataSet.replace(avoid,'');
  if(dataSet.indexOf(avoid) != -1){
      dataSet = dataSet.replace(avoid,'');
  }

  console.log(dataSet);
}

arrayPrepareFunction(11,null,33)
arrayPrepareFunction(11,null,null,44)
arrayPrepareFunction(11,22,null,null)
```

Comment: And what should be returned if nothing is selected?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this is the best answer, but it seams to work:
This puts all the elements into an array >> removes the last few elements if null >> format

```
function arrayPrepareFunction(hpVal,outputRpmVal,ratioVal,outputSpeedVal){
    let arr = [hpVal, outputRpmVal, ratioVal, outputSpeedVal];
    for(let i = arr.length-1; i >= 0; i --){
        if(arr[i] == null) {
            arr.pop();
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    }
    let dataSet = '('
    for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i ++) {
        dataSet += arr[i] + (i != arr.length - 1? ',': '');
    }
    dataSet += ')';
    console.log(dataSet);
}

arrayPrepareFunction(11,null,33);
arrayPrepareFunction(11,null,null,44);
arrayPrepareFunction(11,22,null,null);
```

Outputs:
(11,null,33)
(11,null,null,44)
(11,22)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to construct a string from all the passed arguments and avoid having `null`in the last of the `string`, the best solution would be to treat the inputs as an `array`, make your check for `null` items then transform this `array` into a `string`.

This is how should be your code:

```
function arrayPrepareFunction(hpVal, outputRpmVal, ratioVal, outputSpeedVal) {
  dataSet = Object.values(arguments);

  var i = dataSet.length;
  while (dataSet[i - 1] == null && i > 0) {
    dataSet.pop();
    i--;
  }
    dataSet = "(" + dataSet.map(a => a == null ? "" + a : a).join(", ") + ")";
  console.log(dataSet);
}
```

- It uses `Object.values(arguments)` to get the input arguments
  as `array`.
- Keeps removing last item from the `array` if it is `null`.
- Then transform this `array` into a `string`.

**Demo:**

```js
var dataSet, avoid = ",null";

function arrayPrepareFunction(hpVal, outputRpmVal, ratioVal, outputSpeedVal) {
  dataSet = Object.values(arguments);

  var i = dataSet.length;
  while (dataSet[i - 1] == null && i > 0) {
    dataSet.pop();
    i--;
  }
  dataSet = "(" + dataSet.map(a => a == null ? "" + a : a).join(", ") + ")";
  console.log(dataSet);
}

arrayPrepareFunction(11, null, 33)
arrayPrepareFunction(11, null, null, 44)
arrayPrepareFunction(11, 22, null, null)
```

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is a different approach:

First create an array with the values, it's better to work than a string with all values concated.

Then be sure that you are using a string `"null"` not the value `null`, it will help in your case. (Did that with `.map()`)

After that, loop through the array from back to end, checking for `"null"`, if you find one, then splice/delete it from array, if the value is not null, then stop the loop because it is a valid value.

To finish, just join the array with `,` and you will have what you need.

```js
var dataSet;

function arrayPrepareFunction(hpVal,outputRpmVal,ratioVal,outputSpeedVal){
  dataArray=[hpVal,outputRpmVal,ratioVal,outputSpeedVal];
  dataArray = dataArray.map(function(x){
    if (x == null || typeof x == 'undefined'){
      return "null";
    }else{
      return x;
    }  
  });
  
  for (var i = dataArray.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
  var value = dataArray[i];
    if (value == "null"){
      dataArray.splice(i,1);
    }else{
      break;
    }
  }

  var dataSet = "(" + dataArray.join(",") + ")"
  console.log(dataSet);
}

arrayPrepareFunction(11,null,33)
arrayPrepareFunction(11,null,null,44)
arrayPrepareFunction(11,22,null,null)
```